# How can I know that TestNG framework is suitable to perform test case prioritization in regression testing?

Tags: testcase, regression-testing, testng-eclipse

I have a requirement to know that, whether TestNG framework is suitable for test case prioritization in regression testing to increase the fault rate detection or not? Which also enhance the performance of coverage based techniques based on the correlation value.

Comment: Fancy words, but too broad in my humble opinion. Yes, you can use priorities, dependencies and Groups in testNG to prioritise or control the flow of your tests. The fault rate detection is up to you and how well written your tests are. Should be closed as too broad.

Comment: hi,thanks for your valuable response. I'm new to testing, can it possible to get high correlation between coverage and fault detection by using TestNG?

Comment: TestNG is a good framework to use, will probably cover most of your needs. I will suggest, search in YouTube and start watching some beginner tutorials regarding automation (i.e. search for Selenium + Java or TestNG). Try to complete some of these tutorials on your own computer and when you get stuck on something more specific, come back here and find the answer! Best of luck! :) After reading your title again, I can add that YES testNG is suitable and you can use dependencies or priorities to control the flow of your regression suite. More here..http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html

Comment: Thank You very much Sir, It's very useful for me and now I'm using selenium for my work also I have one more doubt,  is it possible to consider ontology technique in test case prioritization? If so, in what way I can go for it? please suggest me.